# Relay command in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to c# and trying to understand how commands work in mvvm architecture. What I need to do is that updating some info when I click a button. I think I implemented the relay class fine but there is no update at all.

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

**MovieViewModel.cs**

```
class MovieViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Movie _movie;

    private ICommand _updateCommand;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MovieViewModel()
    {
        _movie = new Movie
        {
            Title = "Unknown",
            Genre = "Unknown",
            Price = 11.0,
            Score = 0
        };
    }

    public Movie Movie
    {
        get
        {
            return _movie;
        }
        set
        {
            _movie = value;
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return Movie.Title;
        }
        set
        {
            Movie.Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public string Genre
    {
        get
        {
            return Movie.Genre;
        }
        set
        {
            Movie.Genre = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Genre");
        }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return Movie.Price;
        }
        set
        {
            Movie.Price = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    public double Score
    {
        get
        {
            return Movie.Score;
        }
        set
        {
            Movie.Score = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Score");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_updateCommand == null)
            {
                _updateCommand = new RelayCommand(p => { updateMovie("ASD", "ZXC", 11.90, 0); }, p => true);
            }
            return _updateCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _updateCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public Movie updateMovie(string title, string genre, double price, double score)
    {
        _movie.Title = title;
        _movie.Genre = genre;
        _movie.Price = price;
        _movie.Score = score;

        return _movie;
    }
}
```

**Button command binding**

```
<Button x:Name="updateBtn" Content="Update" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="75" Height="30" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
```

Comment: please specify what is not updating actully

Comment: The only variables there; title, genre, price, and score

Comment: None of this are updating in the interactive ? Please check for binding errors. Why `_movie.Title` you can set to your `public Movie` instead of private variable ,

Comment: They are updating with `INotifyPropertyChanged ` and as far as I can see there is no binding errors. They are not updating when I use `RelayCommand`

Comment: This method get invoked `public Movie updateMovie(string title, string genre, double price, double score)` ?

Comment: Yep. I tracked it in debug, all of those variables change like I want but in the end there is no change at screen.

Comment: Try giving `RaisePropertyChanged("Movie");` too

Comment: @Miral You may also consider visiting [the WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) for help.

Comment: @Eldho has already pointed out the problem. You're not raising PropertyChanged event since you bypass the property and access the underlying fields directly. You should use the VM like it's meant to. The access going through VM to model applies to you just as much as it applies to views and other bound clients to your VM.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would in fact depend on the property values you're changing. So it's impossible to know for sure why they are not being updated. Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and provide a _precise_ description of what the code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho while generally I'd totally agree with your assessment of providing MC&C code sample, in this case the problematic code is in fact in the snippet and both Eldho & myself have already pointed it out (and confirmed in room chat to be the real issue) Please feel free to join us in WPF room. I'd be great to have another experienced wpf developer with us :) [will remove this comment shortly to clean up]

Comment: @Maverik: I respectfully disagree. It's true that if binding to the `Movie` property, failing to raise the event is a problem. But there's not enough information in the question to show that's even being done. Indeed, the OP seems to be concerned about the other property values (i.e. from his comment: _"title, genre, price, and score"_), which do raise the event. I agree his view model implementation is irregular, but without a good [mcve], we can't know for sure what the problem is. We have no idea how he's actually _using_ the `MovieViewModel` object, or even if he's using the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Movie");
```

Thanks @Maverik has given the reason statement too. You're not raising `PropertyChanged` event since you bypass the property and access the underlying fields directly. You should use the VM like it's meant to.

The access going through VM to model applies to you just as much as it applies to views and other bound clients to your VM.

Comment: In the WPF chat room i've told him to just access the data via Properties instead of fields since that is the correct way of doing things but this works too :) Still you may wish to suggest the same (as in accessing via properties)

Comment: @Maverik pls add that as answer so in future some will get benefitted

Comment: No, it's not worth as a competing answer. If you had not already mentioned the core problem of PropertyChanged not getting called, I may have done it. But the comment above should be enough for future visitors.